# MMS Downloading Hangs on Data State Change

Tags: data-connection, mms, nexus-6

As a general rule, I turn my data off and pretty much force everything to be done via WiFi unless I am out and about, at which time I have data turned on obviously.

However, as many know, messaging app (in my case the default Google one) requires data for some reason to down the MMS and won't do it over WiFi (if there is a way to change that behavior, please share) but since my data is off while at home/work, if I receive a MMS message, then it will just sit there with "Tap to download" as the option.

So far that's fine, but when I turn on data at this point and then click on Tap to download, it will just sit there forever saying downloading but not actually downloading anything. It is not until I restart the phone that clicking Tap to download instantly download the MMS. This makes no sense to me and I would like to understand what's going on here.

My question is basically, WHY doesn't turning the data back on not successfully download the MMS without having to restart the phone? What is preventing the system from honoring/recognizing the data state change and availability here? TIA

Comment: Hi! Have you considered force-stopping the app, and then launching it to download the MMS? Also, does the download takes place using "Downloads" app of Android or by the app's own downloads?

Comment: Yes I have hard terminated the app and ran it again to no avail. As for the second part of your question, I have no idea what you mean and don't understand your question, sorry. But if I have to venture a guess as to what you mean, the downloading is done inside the default messenger app, like it is normally, there is no external downloading, MMS download don't work like that as outside download links.